# How to make the chapter number 1 inch from top of page?

Tags: margins, titlesec

I'm writing a thesis, and the department requires all main headings;i.e., chapter numbers (including the title of table of contents) to be 1 inch from top of of the page. I'm using `\usepackage[margin=1in]{geometry}`. In another post, someone suggested that I use

```
\usepackage{titlesec}
\titleformat{\chapter}[display]{\centering \Large}{\chaptertitlename\ \thechapter}  {1ex}{}{}
\titlespacing{\chapter}{0pt}{0pt}{0pt}
```

But still the headings are not 1 inch from top. Also this doesn't change the spacing for the title of table of contents.

Here's my code:

```
\documentclass[12]{report}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[margin=1in]{geometry}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{tikz-cd}
\usepackage{enumerate}
\usepackage{tocloft}
\usepackage{parskip}
\usepackage{indentfirst}
\setlength{\parindent}{1cm}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage[nottoc]{tocbibind}
\usepackage{sectsty}
%\usepackage{hyperref}
%\usepackage[linktocpage=true]{hyperref}
\setlength{\cftbeforetoctitleskip}{2mm}
\renewcommand{\cftchapfont}{\normalfont}
\renewcommand{\cftchappagefont}{\normalfont}
\renewcommand{\cfttoctitlefont}{\hfill \Large}
\renewcommand{\cftaftertoctitle}{\hfill\hfill}
\renewcommand{\contentsname}{Table of Contents}

\usepackage{titlesec}
\titleformat{\chapter}[display]{\centering \Large}{\chaptertitlename\ \thechapter}{1ex}{}{}
\titlespacing{\chapter}{0pt}{0pt}{0pt}

\chapternumberfont{\centering \large}
\chaptertitlefont{\centering \large}
\sectionfont{\large}

\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}[section]
\newtheorem{corollary}[theorem]{Corollary}
\newtheorem{proposition}[theorem]{Proposition}
\newtheorem{lemma}[theorem]{Lemma}
\theoremstyle{definition}
\newtheorem*{definition}{Definition}
\theoremstyle{remark}
\newtheorem*{remark}{Remark}
\newtheorem{case}{Case}
\newtheorem{example}[theorem]{Example}\newcommand{\gen}[1]{\langle #1\rangle}
\newcommand{\F}{\mathbb{F}}
\newcommand{\Z}{\mathbb{Z}}
\newcommand{\C}{\mathbb{C}}
\newcommand{\N}{\text{N}}
\newcommand{\T}{\text{T}}
\newcommand{\Tr}{\text{Tr}}
\newcommand{\legendre}[2]{\ensuremath{\left(\frac{#1}{#2}}\right)}


% For signature page
\newcommand{\signaturerule}{\rule{20em}{.4pt}}
\newcommand{\daterule}{\rule{10em}{.4pt}}


\begin{document}

\input{Titlepage}

\pagenumbering{roman}

\setcounter{page}{2}\doublespacing

\tableofcontents


\pagebreak

% Abstract page

\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Abstract}
\chapter*{Abstract}\pagebreak
\pagenumbering{arabic}

\chapter{Preliminaries}
\input{chapters/Preliminaries}

\chapter{Main Results}
\input{chapters/chapter2}

\chapter{}
\input{chapters/chapter3}

\chapter{}
\input{chapters/chapter4}



\bibliographystyle{plain}
\bibliography{bibliography.bib}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 0):

As far as I can see you've got the inch. See below, screenshot from Acroreader. To enable frames showing your layout settings use `\usepackage[showframe]{geometry}`. Frankly, `geometry` should do the job w.o. need for further adjustments.

What might be under discussion is the red area I indicated. However, I think moving sections headers fürther up can be demanded. But I'd make sure that's what they want you to do.

I adjusted your code a little bit, as we don't have your 5 files you `\input`. See `% <<<` in the code.

[image: acroread]

```
\documentclass[12]{report}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[margin=1in, showframe]{geometry}% <<<
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{tikz-cd}
\usepackage{enumerate}
\usepackage{tocloft}
\usepackage{parskip}
\usepackage{indentfirst}
\setlength{\parindent}{1cm}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage[nottoc]{tocbibind}
\usepackage{sectsty}
%\usepackage{hyperref}
%\usepackage[linktocpage=true]{hyperref}

\usepackage{blindtext}% <<< workaround

\setlength{\cftbeforetoctitleskip}{2mm}
\renewcommand{\cftchapfont}{\normalfont}
\renewcommand{\cftchappagefont}{\normalfont}
\renewcommand{\cfttoctitlefont}{\hfill \Large}
\renewcommand{\cftaftertoctitle}{\hfill\hfill}
\renewcommand{\contentsname}{Table of Contents}

\usepackage{titlesec}
\titleformat{\chapter}[display]{\centering \Large}{\chaptertitlename\ \thechapter}{1ex}{}{}
\titlespacing{\chapter}{0pt}{0pt}{0pt}

\chapternumberfont{\centering \large}
\chaptertitlefont{\centering \large}
\sectionfont{\large}

\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}[section]
\newtheorem{corollary}[theorem]{Corollary}
\newtheorem{proposition}[theorem]{Proposition}
\newtheorem{lemma}[theorem]{Lemma}
\theoremstyle{definition}
\newtheorem*{definition}{Definition}
\theoremstyle{remark}
\newtheorem*{remark}{Remark}
\newtheorem{case}{Case}
\newtheorem{example}[theorem]{Example}\newcommand{\gen}[1]{\langle #1\rangle}
\newcommand{\F}{\mathbb{F}}
\newcommand{\Z}{\mathbb{Z}}
\newcommand{\C}{\mathbb{C}}
\newcommand{\N}{\text{N}}
\newcommand{\T}{\text{T}}
\newcommand{\Tr}{\text{Tr}}
\newcommand{\legendre}[2]{\ensuremath{\left(\frac{#1}{#2}}\right)}


% For signature page
\newcommand{\signaturerule}{\rule{20em}{.4pt}}
\newcommand{\daterule}{\rule{10em}{.4pt}}


\begin{document}

%\input{Titlepage}% ! MISSING

\blindtext{}% <<< workaround

\pagenumbering{roman}

\setcounter{page}{2}\doublespacing

\tableofcontents


\pagebreak

% Abstract page

\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Abstract}
\chapter*{Abstract}\pagebreak
\pagenumbering{arabic}

\chapter{Preliminaries}
%\input{chapters/Preliminaries}

\blindtext{}% <<< workaround


\chapter{Main Results}
%\input{chapters/chapter2}
\blindtext{}% <<< workaround

\chapter{}
%\input{chapters/chapter3}
\blindtext{}% <<< workaround

\chapter{}
%\input{chapters/chapter4}
\blindtext{}% <<< workaround


\bibliographystyle{plain}
%\bibliography{bibliography.bib}
\blindtext{}% <<< workaround
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you for this. Is the frame considered the top of the page? I think our department means 1 inch from the edge of the page. Also how can I fix the same thing for the table of contents? I used `\setlength{\cftbeforetoctitleskip}{2mm}` which is not 1 inch even to the top of the frame.

Comment: The `toc` etc. title is set using the `\chapter*` command, so perhaps you have to adjust that.